# R ‘VennDiagram’ - Equal size ellipses

Tags: r, venn-diagram

Here is the example from the VennDiagram documentation:

```
  venn.plot <- draw.quad.venn(
  area1 = 80,
  area2 = 80,
  area3 = 80,
  area4 = 80,
  n12 = 44,
  n13 = 27,
  n14 = 32,
  n23 = 38,
  n24 = 32,
  n34 = 20,
  n123 = 18,
  n124 = 17,
  n134 = 11,
  n234 = 13,
  n1234 = 6,
  category = c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"),
  fill = c("orange", "red", "green", "blue"),
  lty = "dashed",
  cex = 2,
  cat.cex = 2,
  cat.col = c("orange", "red", "green", "blue")
);
```

The 'third' and 'fourth' ellipses are smaller than the others even though they are of equal size. I know I can't scale each overlap to equal the size of the overlap. Is it possible to make all four shapes the same size ?

[four-way venn diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFUMl.png)